# Using pthread on Linux 2.4 - getting "incomplete type" compilation error

Tags: linux, pthreads, incomplete-type

I'm working on Linux 2.4 (doing h.w for my O.S course),
I want to use pthread to implement a reader-writer lock.
In rw_lock.c I have:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "rw_lock.h"

struct readers_writers_t
{
    int prio;
    int number_of_readers;
    pthread_cond_t no_readers;
    int number_of_writers;
    int number_of_waiting_writers;
    pthread_cond_t no_writers;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
};

[functions...]
```

in rw_lock.h I have:

```
typedef struct readers_writers_t readers_writers;
```

In another C file (implementation of linked list) I have :

```
#include "rw_lock.h"

struct LinkedList
{
    ListNode* head;
    ListNode* tail;
    readers_writers rwLock;
};

(and more functions,includes etc').
```

I get (one) compilation error :

> "rwLock has incomplete type".

I have no idea why I get this error (or how to fix it...).

help is appreciated,thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linked list C file does not know about the `struct readers_writers_t`, it's defined within your rw_lock.c file.

1. You should just move your struct readers_writers_t out of rw_lock.c and into your rw_lock.h file.
2. Or perhaps you don't want your linked list to know about that struct. In that case, you should define the `readers_writers rwLock` as a pointer (readers_writers *rwLock) rather. Another alternative is to 
   make your readers_writers typedef a pointer: `typedef struct readers_writers_t *readers_writers`
   This requires that functions in  rw_lock.c allocates space for the actual struct, as that's the only file that knows about the actual struct.

Comment: thank you,
why if the list does not know about struct readers_writers_t
I get incomplete type,but a pointer to struct readers_writers_t is fine ?

Comment: If you use the struct itself, your linked list have to know how it's defined, otherwise it doesn't know how much storage to allocate for it. When you use a pointer, the compiler knows that all it has to do is allocate enough storage for a pointer, the compiler treats all pointers the same and doesn't need the struct itself. However if you want to dereference the pointer to work with any of the struct members, you do need to provide the struct definition.

Answer (score 3):

You need to move the structure defintion from the source file to the header file.

rw_lock.h should be:

```
#ifndef  SOME_UNIQUE_STRING_MY_RW_LOCK_H
#define  SOME_UNIQUE_STRING_MY_RW_LOCK_H

#include <pthread.h>

struct readers_writers_t
{
    int prio;
    int number_of_readers;
    pthread_cond_t no_readers;
    int number_of_writers;
    int number_of_waiting_writers;
    pthread_cond_t no_writers;
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
};
typedef struct readers_writers_t readers_writers;

#endif
```